# Oracle SQL -- Using A Date Function to improve a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
 --Retention by DOC,Users created >= Jan 1,2012--
Select 
One.Date_Of_Concern,
Two.Users, 
One.Retained,
Round(One.Retained/Two.Users,4) as Perc_Retained
From
(
Select 
To_Date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd')As Date_Of_Concern,
Count(P.Player_Id) As Retained
From Player P
Where
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
 And
(To_Date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd')-Trunc(P.Init_Dtime))<=7
 ) One
Inner Join
(
Select 
To_Date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd')As Date_Of_Concern,
Count(P.Player_Id) As Users
From Player P
Where
Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
) Two On One.Date_Of_Concern = Two.Date_Of_Concern
```

Which Gives Me a Result of 1 Row:

```
Date_Of_Concern     USERS     RETAINED     PERC_RETAINED
09-Sep-12            449773    78983        0.1756
```

I would like to improve this query by adding in some sort of date changing methodology. That way, I won't have to run the query each time for 09-sep-12, 10-sep-12, 11-sep-12, and so on. Instead, it will all show up in the same query, like this:

```
Date_Of_Concern     USERS     RETAINED     PERC_RETAINED
09-Sep-12            449773    48783        0.1756
10-Sep-12            449773    46777        0.1600
11-Sep-12            440773    44852        0.1500
12-Sep-12            349773    42584         0.1400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with the given information, i don't know if you have any table you can join and bring those dates. However, if you do not, you could try this:

We have to generate rows and reproduce the dates in a sequential form. But first, lets give a look at how to generate rows:

Generate 5 rows:

```
SELECT rownum 
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

 ROWNUM
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

Now, applying this to reproduce a data source for your dates:

```
SELECT to_date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd') + (rownum -1) as Date_Of_Concern
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

 Date_Of_Concern
----------
 2012-sep-09
 2012-sep-10
 2012-sep-11
 2012-sep-12
 2012-sep-13
```

Obviously you will need a start date. Additionally, the number 5 has to be replaced by the number of dates you need, it could be a date range like

```
SELECT to_date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd') + (rownum -1) date
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('2012-sep-20','yyyy-mon-dd') - to_date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd'));
```

OK, now the final result would look like this:

```
SELECT  both.Date_Of_Concern,
        both.Retained,
        both.Users,
        Round(both.Retained/both.Users,4) as Perc_Retained
  FROM (select Date_Of_Concern,
              (Select Count(P.Player_Id) As Retained
                From Player P
                Where Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
                  And (Date_Of_Concern-Trunc(P.Init_Dtime))<=7) Retained,
              (Select Count(P.Player_Id) As Users
                    From Player P
                    Where Trunc(P.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
                ) Users
          from (SELECT to_date('2012-sep-09','yyyy-mon-dd') + (rownum -1) Date_Of_Concern,
                FROM dual 
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5)) both
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks for taking the time to explain it thoroughly. Now I can use this knowledge later too!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your query can be simplified a lot. Here is an attempt to list day by day from the beginning of 2012. Depends what kind of range you are looking for.

```
SELECT date_of_concern
      ,Running_Total_Users AS Users
      ,Running_Total_Retained As Retained
      ,ROUND(Running_Total_Retained / Running_Total_Users, 4) AS Perc_Retained

  FROM ( SELECT date_of_concern

               ,SUM(Users) OVER( ORDER BY date_of_concern
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND CURRENT ROW ) AS Running_Total_Users

               ,SUM(Retained) OVER( ORDER BY date_of_concern
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND CURRENT ROW ) AS Running_Total_Retained

           FROM ( SELECT TRUNC(Create_Dtime) date_of_concern
                        ,COUNT(Player_Id) Users
                        ,SUM( CASE WHEN (TRUNC(Create_Dtime) - TRUNC(Init_Dtime)) <= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Retained
                    FROM player ON ( TRUNC(.Create_Dtime) >= TO_DATE('2012', 'YYYY') )
                )
        )
```

The inner most query is an attempt to re-write the posted query counting from day 1 (Jan 1 2012). Then the next wrapper is supposed to do running totals for each subsequent day. The final wrapper is to enable the `Perc_Retained`. Completed untested of course :)

Comment: It doesn't appear like there is a relation between Create_Dtime and date_of_concern. It appears like date_of_concern is an arbitrary date.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders The original query is doing a running total from the beginning of the year to the date_of_concern. I'm doing (attempting?) the running total for each day from the beginning of the year with the result of calculating a "date_of_concern" for each day of the year. It isn't really clear what kind of range is desired, or if it should be a rolling window related to the current date, or some other range...

Comment: Date_Of_Concern is the most important date..because for each date of concern, only the "Trunc(P.Init_Dtime)" that is within 7 days of the date of concern is counted as retained for that date. I have used a running total as tracking retention in a different manner, but for the purposes of this one, I am trying to base it all of the date_of_concern.

Comment: @Stuav It is accounted for in with the CASE statement. The request seemed to be for multiple "date_of_concerns", this was meant to show every day of the year as a date_of_concern. I think the join of "One" and "Two" of the posted query could be simplified to a single query using the SUM(CASE..) portion. Just trying to show some alternate ideas. It is kind of interesting, but would really need sample data and structure to take it further.  Cheers.